# Nuclide Flow not showing errors in Atom

Tags: atom-editor, flowtype, nuclide-editor

I have a small project to test out [facebook flow](https://flowtype.org/). I have purposefully placed some type errors that flow picks up, and they are successfully detected when running `flow check` from the command line.

I would like to display them directly on Atom, when viewing the file(s), but currently it shows 0 errors (about 20 in the project when running from command line). Here is what I've done:

- Installed **flow** (with brew)
- Installed **Nuclide** from the Atom packages (settings shown in image below)
- initialized an empty `.flowconfig` file in the project
- Initialize each file to flow-check with `/* @flow */`
- run `flow check` from the project directory

I have the following OS versions:

- OSX 10.11
- Atom 1.8.0
- Nuclide 0.141.0
- Flow 0.14.0

Here are my *settings for Nuclide flow*:
[image: Nuclide-flow Atom settings]

Here is what I get when running flow on the command line:
[image: command line output]
Here is what I get when viewing file on Atom:
[image]

Comment: If all else fails, there's now another setting under "Flow" in Nuclide Settings: `Use the Flow binary included in each project's flow-bin`. Assuming you install flow-bin as part of your project's devDependencies, it might work. (This is not recommended, but alas, in my case turned out to be the only solution that actually worked.)

Comment: I met similar problem, and "Go to definition" is not working as well. Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 5):

I have actually just made it work by doing the following:

- update flow to 0.26.0 with `brew upgrade flow` (or `sudo brew upgrade flow` if you need to)
- disable all linter packages on Atom
- restart atom (shutting the app completely first)
- Restart Flow Server (Atom top bar --> Nuclide --> flow --> Restart Flow Server)